# Why does size of UIImageView change on scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView set to fill a UICollectionViewCell. Here is the code:

```
// Note: image is a UIImage
// Note: cell is a UICollectionViewCell
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
imageView.frame = cell.bounds
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
```

However when the keyboard dismisses and the view scrolls up, the size of the images seem to change with the scroll. Here are two videos at different animation speeds so you can see the problem:

[image: Slow Speed]

[image: Normal Speed]
<sub>(source: [giphy.com](https://i.giphy.com/8XPWTWZJlLvoY.gif))</sub>

Why are they resizing like that? I just want them to be a constant size.

You can see in the normal speed one that when you scroll up manually there is no issue, but when you tap the "Done" button and the keyboard dismisses the resizing happens.

Comment: are you using autolayout ? , where you put that code, possible reason for that is reuse cell

Comment: @MikeAlter for the cells I am not using auto layout. Before reuse the image views are removed. That code is called from `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.